# How to multithread a computationally intensive code segment in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I hava a java program, a section of it is compute intensive, like this

```
for i = 1 :512
   COMPUTE INTENSIVE SECTION
end
```

I want to split it into multithread, make it faster when running.

COMPUTE INTENSIVE SECTION is not sequential-wise. It means running i=1 first or i=5 fist are the same...

Can anybody give me a grand guide about this. How to do it?
Thanks indeed!
Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: The "grand guide" to this is the excellent book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/), by Brian Goetz et al.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html The Fork/Join Framework is built for exactely that case (and others, too :-). Warning: JDK7 only.

Comment: BTW does anybody know why Oracle puts JDK7 links in the tutorial long before a release version of JDK7 is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a thread pool would be good.  Basically, you whip up a collection of N different threads, then request them in a loop.  The request blocks until a thread is available.

```
ThreadPool pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // 10 threads in the pool
ArrayList<Callable> collectionOfCallables = new ArrayList<Callable>( );
for (...) {
  Callable callable = new Callable<Foo>() { public Foo call() { COMPUTE INTENSIVE SECTION } }
  collectionOfCallables.add(callable);
}

ArrayList<Future<Foo>> results = pool.invokeAll( collectionOfCallables );

pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES ); // blocks till everything is done or 5 minutes have passed.
```

With the Future's you really don't need to await termination.  get()ing the result from a future will block until the corresponding thread is done (or canceled).

Comment: You might find Runtime.availableProcessors() is a good size for you thread pool. It can be used to dynamically change the pool size dependant on the size of your machine.

Comment: Depending on what is happening, 1 thread per processor may not be the best way to go... particularly when you take processor tricks like "hyper threading" into account.  Processor count will certainly be a factor though... good point.

Answer (score 5):

You should read the [Concurrency Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency) of the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial). Especially [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) and [Thread Pools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) should be relevant for you.

Basically, you create a thread pool (which is an `Executor`) through one of the factory methods in [the `Executors` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and submit `Runnable` instances to it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
    executor.execute(new Runnable(){public void run(){
        // your heavy code goes here
    }});
}
```

Comment: If it is a computation intensive task, using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().getAvailableProcessors())` as the executor is a good bet for the number of thread in the thread pool.

Answer (score 3):

Look at any Java multi-threading tutorial, either the official one:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

or some of the others, e.g.:

- Very nice in my opinion - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-threads/section2.html
- Short one - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm
- A bit succinct and touches a bit more then basics - http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sean Patrick Floyd's answer, but a bit less verbose with a lambda expression:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
    es.execute(() -> {
        // code goes here
    });
}
```

Comment: So, this is possible from Java 8 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you can split your intensive action to recursive smaller sub tasks, [ForkJoinPool](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-fork-and-join-forkjoinpool.html)  is ideal for you.

If your server is running with `8 core CPU`, you can set the pool size as 8

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(8);
```

OR

you can use [Executor Service](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) `FixedThreadPool` by moving compute intensive task to `Callable` as below

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Your compute intensive task");
}
});

future.get();  //returns null if the task has finished correctly.
```

There is one advantage with `ForkJoinPool`. Idle threads will steal jobs from busy threads from blokcingQueue where your `Runnable/Callable` tasks have been submitted.

Java 8 added one more new API in `Executors` : [newWorkStealingPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--)

If you need to wait for completion of all tasks, use can use `invokeAll()` on `ExecutorService`.

Have a look at this [article](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) by `Benjamin` for advanced concurrent APIs using Java 8