# How to create 4 threads to add elements into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

How could this code be adapted in order to split arr1 into 4 parts and create 4 threads to add elements into intlist1. Thread #1 process first quarter of arr1, thread #2 process the second quarter, thread #3 process third quarter and thread #4 process the last quarter of arr1. Note that intList1 will be used later.

```
void process() throws IOException {

    List<Integer> intList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1 .length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
            if (arr1 [i][2] == arr2[j]) {
                intList1.add(arr1 [i][0]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (intList1.size() > 0) {
        // some code here
    }

}
```

Comment: ArrayList is not thread-safe meaning, you are guaranteed to loose data when you write from multiple threads into it. When you use a thread-safe collection (e.g. CopyOnWriteArrayList) you need a very big input for the threading to provide you an advantage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to multithread a computationally intensive code segment in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272774/how-to-multithread-a-computationally-intensive-code-segment-in-java)

Comment: @ValerijDobler, arr1 is very big (40,000,000 * 3). I read the answer you sugested, but my knowledge is limited and I do not know how to apply it to this code, Could you please help me adapt this code with your suggestion?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service for writing programs for free. Please attempt your project, and if you run into any specific issues come back with the code and ask a question then (after doing some research).

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a very big hammer to use that does not look like a good fit here. From Javadoc: _"all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array"_ and  _"This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations"_ – so it _might_ be faster if you're reading way more than writing. If you're not doing that, it's probably terrible. Just use `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`.

Comment: Javadoc link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) (couldn't post above due to character limit)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's actually 4 threads, but I think its correct way to do this with multithreading.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // CREATE arr1 ARRAY OF INTEGERS
        int arr1[] = new int[40];
        for(int i = 0;i < arr1.length;i++) arr1[i] = i;

        // CREATE intList1 empty ArrayList and thread safe sintList
        List<Integer> intList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> sintList1 = Collections.synchronizedList(intList1);

        // PRINT arr1 CONTENT (INCREASING)
        for(int i : arr1) System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();

        // PROCESS ARRAY WITH MULTIPLE THREADS
        Arrays.stream(arr1).parallel().forEach(x -> sintList1.add(x));

        // PRINT intList1 CONTENT (MESSED UP BY MULTIPLE THREADS)
        for(int i : intList1) System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();

        // OPERATION IS THREADSAFE IF SUM OF ELEMENTS IS EQUAL AFTER OPERATION
        int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
        for(int i : arr1) s1 += i;
        for(int i : intList1) s2 += i;

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);

    }

}
```

My output is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
26 25 28 29 27 22 24 23 21 20 36 35 38 39 37 6 33 30 31 16 5 15 12 8 14 2 9 13 4 11 7 3 10 1 0 32 34 17 19 18 
780
780
```

EDIT:

arr1 is 2D array, I missed it. Also, you said, arr1 is `(40,000,000 * 3)`, make it `(3 * 40,000,000)`, otherwise I don't know any simple solution.

```java
// CREATE arr1 2D ARRAY OF INTEGERS
        int n = 3, m = 40;
        int arr1[][] = new int[n][m];
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
            for(int j = 0;j < m;j++)
                arr1[i][j] = j;

        // CREATE arr2 ARRAY OF INTEGERS
        int arr2[] = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0;i < arr2.length;i++) arr2[i] = i;

        // CREATE intList1 empty ArrayList and thread safe sintList
        List<Integer> intList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> sintList1 = Collections.synchronizedList(intList1);

        // PRINT arr1 CONTENT (INCREASING)
        for(int i : arr1[2]) System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();

        // PROCESS ARRAY WITH MULTIPLE THREADS
        Arrays.stream(arr1[2]).parallel().forEach(x -> {
            for(int i : arr2) if(i == x) sintList1.add(x);
        });

        // PRINT intList1 CONTENT (MESSED UP BY MULTIPLE THREADS)
        for(int i : intList1) System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();

        // OPERATION IS THREADSAFE IF SUM OF ELEMENTS IS EQUAL AFTER OPERATION
        int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++) s1 += arr1[2][i];
        for(int i : intList1) s2 += i;

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: In order to add an element into sintList1, first I need to check if the element in the third column of arr1 is also in arr2, and if this is true, then add the element in the first column of arr1 into sintList1. So, I'm trying to write a code like: `Arrays.stream(arr1).parallel().forEach((x) -> {
            for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
                if (arr1[x][2] == arr2[j]) {
                    sintList1.add(arr1[x][0]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });` . Unfortunately, NetBeans shows there is a problem. Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: I suggest you to provide an error message next time instead of saying `Unfortunately, NetBeans shows there is a problem.` and analyze given example more precisely. Good luck.